# SocketException (995) with EF Core and Pomelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

My application sometimes throws this exception:
`MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired. All pooled connections are in use.`

I found out from my hosting provider that there were a lot of idle connection in the mysql from my application.

Hence I tried disabled pooling by adding `POOLING=FALSE` in the connection string. Instead I got the following exception.

```
 ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): The Command Timeout expired before the operation completed.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.StreamByteHandler.<ReadBytesAsync>g__DoReadBytesAsync|6_2(Memory`1 buffer) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/StreamByteHandler.cs:line 89
   at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.StreamByteHandler.<ReadBytesAsync>g__DoReadBytesAsync|6_2(Memory`1 buffer) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/StreamByteHandler.cs:line 89
   at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.BufferedByteReader.ReadBytesAsync(IByteHandler byteHandler, ArraySegment`1 buffer, Int32 totalBytesToRead, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/BufferedByteReader.cs:line 36
   at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.ProtocolUtility.<ReadPacketAsync>g__AddContinuation|1_0(ValueTask`1 headerBytes, BufferedByteReader bufferedByteReader, IByteHandler byteHandler, Func`1 getNextSequenceNumber, ProtocolErrorBehavior protocolErrorBehavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/ProtocolUtility.cs:line 412
   at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.ProtocolUtility.<DoReadPayloadAsync>g__AddContinuation|5_0(ValueTask`1 readPacketTask, BufferedByteReader bufferedByteReader, IByteHandler byteHandler, Func`1 getNextSequenceNumber, ArraySegmentHolder`1 previousPayloads, ProtocolErrorBehavior protocolErrorBehavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/ProtocolUtility.cs:line 483
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 890
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 119
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 445
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 60
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 315
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 307
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.GetRolesAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1.CreateAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1.SecurityStampVerified(TUser user, CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I would like to know what caused this exception and what is the better way to handle the idle mysql connections issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence I tried disabled pooling by adding `POOLING=FALSE` in the connection string. Instead I got the following exception.

The reason you got the `---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): The Command Timeout expired before the operation completed.` exception is likely, that the max. connections of your MySQL instance are already exhausted.

If you don't want to reconfigure your MySQL instance, the simplest way to get your app to run is to disable connection pooling (as you already did) and then restart your server (to ensure that no still existing connections from your old code are preventing you from connecting).

---

If you want to use connection pooling after all, you might also want to look at the [Connection Pooling Options](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#connection-pooling-options) of MySqlConnector.

They contain options to manage the number of connections and their lifetime for your connection pool (the default number is `100` and the default lifetime is infinite).

Especially take a closer look at `MaxPoolSize` and `ConnectionIdleTimeout`.

Also, make sure that your connection string does not change. MySqlConnector (and therefore Pomelo) uses a dedicated connection pool for each unique connection string.

---

In addition to that, on the MySQL database level, you can force connections to be closed after a specific timeout with the `wait_timeout` option.

It's default value is usually `28800` (8 hours).

Comment: Are there any downsides to limiting number of `MaxPoolSize`?

Comment: If you create more connections than `MaxPoolSize` then those excess connections will be closed instead of returned to the pool once you are done with them. So if `MaxPoolSize` is very small, not all connections might get the benefit of the pool.
However, if your database is local (same machine or network as the app), the overhead of not pooling is negligible for most applications.
You should make sure, that the sum of the `MaxPoolSize` values of all connection pools of all applications that are using the same MySQL instance is lower than the `max_connections` value of that MySQL instance.

Comment: Understood. For my case, I am using a shared hosting service, I'm not sure is the database hosted on the same server as my application. But my hosting provider is complaining that there are many idle MySQL connections from my application, so I will need to reduce the number of `MaxPoolSize`.

Comment: BTW, what exact version of Pomelo and MySqlConnector are you using?

Comment: I was using v5.0.0, but I'm upgrading my application to dotnet 6, hence will be upgrading to latest v6.0.0.

Comment: No, I mean the _exact_ versions of the _Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql_ and _MySqlConnector_ packages. I ask, because there is a known bug in a specific version of MySqlConnector, that could be connected to your issue. (But if you are using Pomelo 5.0.x, this is not an issue for you, because it uses a minimum version of MySqlConnector, that already contains the bugfix.)

Comment: I'm using this nuget package`<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.0" />`. Previously i was using 5.0.1

Comment: In case it is relevant, also see ["Cannot Open when State is Connecting." with AddDbContextPool. #1577](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1577).

Answer (score 0):

1.Connection Timeout=300 (Time in seconds)

2.Default command timeout=300 (Time in seconds)

Use your connection like this:-

```
"ConnectionStrings": {  
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost; port=3306; database=dbname; user=username; password=yourpassword; Persist Security Info=False; Connect Timeout=300;default command timeout=300"  
  }
```

Or

```
"server=yourservername;userid=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;database=xxxxx;Connection Timeout=300;default command timeout=300"
```

Or you can define Time out on Startup class as follows:-

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContextName>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), o => o.CommandTimeout(180)));
```

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: May I know does this resolve the idle connection issue or the IO has been aborted issue?

Comment: @RyanTeh Maybe connection issue.because your command timeout expired that you were found this issue. I just declare a time of the range to my answer and it will work.

Comment: it seems to be connection timeout issue. I copied and pasted the connection string provided by the hosting provider into my config file and never really have a proper looked at it prior to this. I reviewed the connection string, the connection time out was set to 60 in the connection string provided by the hosting provider. Maybe that is the cause of the connection timeout. I have tried your suggestion and will monitor this for a few more days.